# QSlider change the number of increments/decrements when using the mouse wheel

Tags: c++, qt

I have the following slider that currently goes from 1 to 2 in 12 steps on mouse wheel and keyboard arrows, what I want to make it do is to it takes 24 steps to go from 2 to 24?

```
QSlider *slider_speed = new QSlider;
  slider_speed->setOrientation(Qt::Horizontal);
  slider_speed->setTickPosition(QSlider::TicksAbove);
  slider_speed->setRange(-12, 12);
  slider_speed->setSingleStep(1);
  slider_speed->setPageStep(4);
  slider_speed->setTickInterval(12);
```

Comment: I dont really get it, if the slider value is 1 you want by one step to go to `1 + 1/12`? Or stay at 1 and after 12 steps go directy to 2?

Comment: @C137 currently the slider needs 12 keystrokes to go from x1.0.0 to x2.0.0. What I want is to make it so it needs 24 keystrokes to go from x1.0.0 to x2.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Before I do anything I should have checked the source code better :)

To change the steps I just had to change to range and tick interval to 24. And single step to 1. What confused me was a text label in the source code which would have shown a value better than 2.00 which messed me up since wasn't paying attention that that value was set my another function.